# How do I substitute the following string in Excel using =SUBSTITUTE

Tags: excel, excel-formula, substitution, excel-2016

Using =SUBSTITUTE

I have the string in A1:

*[{"LeadPhoneID":3337624,"CallDate":"/Date(1495638988456+0100)/","UtcCallDate":"/Date(1495638988456+0100)/","Attempt":0,"Status":2,"ResultCode":"OE04","LeftMessage":false,"UserID":223,"Notes":""}]*

I am trying just to extract the data in the notes field: "Notes":"" only.

I have tried the following in A2 but doesn't work, it seems like an issue with the characters within the string corrupting my formula.

Any help would be appreciated with this.

Thank you :)

*Note:* For strings were the variables differ I will replace with wildcards for example:

*"CallDate":"/Date(1495638988456+0100)/"
"CallDate":"/Date(??????????????????)/"*

Comment: I notice on another post that I can escape quotations by doubling them up within the formula quotes but in this case that is not feasible as have 12000 records to be worked each time. Is their a way to define the whole things as a string. I have also tried:  =SUBSTITUTE(A1,"'LeadPhoneID":3337624,"'CallDate":"\/Date(1495638988456+0100)\/","UtcCallDate":"\/Date(1495638988456+0100)\/","Attempt":0,"Status":2,"ResultCode":"OE04","LeftMessage":false,"UserID":223,"Notes":""'","")

Comment: Does this work for you `=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,SEARCH("Notes",A1,1),SEARCH("}",A1,1)),"}]","")`?  For me it returns `Notes":"These are my notes"`

Comment: Thanks @BruceWayne it returns Notes":""}] I am looking for just the charachters after Notes":" and before "}]

Comment: How's this (sorry, it isn't very pretty): `=MID(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,SEARCH("Notes",A1,1),SEARCH("}",A1,1)),"}]",""),FIND(":",SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,SEARCH("Notes",A1,1),SEARCH("}",A1,1)),"}]",""))+2,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,SEARCH("Notes",A1,1),SEARCH("}",A1,1)),"}]",""))-FIND(":",SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,SEARCH("Notes",A1,1),SEARCH("}",A1,1)),"}]",""))-2)`

Comment: @BruceWayne it throws an error in the formula so I can't test however I am beginning to understand how your breaking it down, so shall try and figure it out based on what you have provided. In other strings these pairs will be duplicated I imagine this process won't work for that. I am looking to strip out specific strings that I know will remain constant except for the values that I would ?

Comment: Can you post more sample data, and the expected output for each string? Will `Notes":"` always be at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Following formula should work:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("Notes",A1),SEARCH("}]",A1)-SEARCH("Notes",A1))
```

See image for reference.

For `Cell A1` as `[{"LeadPhoneID":3337624,"CallDate":"/Date(1495638988456+0100)/","UtcCallDate":"/Date(1495638988456+0100)/","Attempt":0,"Status":2,"ResultCode":"OE04","LeftMessage":false,"UserID":223,"Notes":"Test Note"}]`

[image]

For `Cell A1` as `[{"LeadPhoneID":3337624,"CallDate":"/Date(1495638988456+0100)/","UtcCallDate":"/Date(1495638988456+0100)/","Attempt":0,"Status":2,"ResultCode":"OE04","LeftMessage":false,"UserID":223,"Notes":""}]`

[image]

**EDIT :________________________________________________________________________**

To get `Test Note` as result use following  formula:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("Notes",A1)+8,SEARCH("}]",A1)-SEARCH("Notes",A1)-9)
```

Comment: Thank you @Mrig it is just Test Note that I need to get out and not Notes":"" is this possible? As I will then concatenate the notes together as this sequence of strings is likely to repeat on some records ie. multiple notes. Is it a case of using another MID at the end of the string to take off the leading characters as well?